# Django - пустое значение в request.META.HTTP_REFERER

Tags: django

Использую Django 1.10.2. Пока тестирую, запуская через "встроенный " веб-сервер. Собственно, задача - добавить в админку действие, которое будет отображать "промежуточную" страницу :

```
def train_classifier(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    operations = []
    for classifier in queryset:
        operations.append(classifier.train_celery().pk)
    context = Context({'operations': operations, 'title': 'Train classifiers'})
    response = HttpResponse(get_template("operations.html").render(context))
    return response
train_classifier.short_description = 'Train classifiers'
...
class ClassifierAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ClassifierModelForm
    actions = [train_classifier, test_classifier]
```

На этой промежуточной странице необходимо по завершении операции показать ссылку обратно к списку классификаторов.

Для чего использую следующий код

```
<a href="{{request.META.HTTP_REFERER}}">Go back</a>
```

Ну и такие связанные с шаблонами настройки в settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            ]
        },
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
    }
]
```

Однако - после перехода от списка объектов к действию - на полученной странице шаблон отрендерен так

```
<a href="">Go back</a>
```

Т.е. `{{request.META.HTTP_REFERER}}` рендерится как пустой текст.
Собственно, что я могу делать не так (и нет ли какого-то лучшего пути проделать это)?

p.s. как временное решение использовал request.META['PATH_INFO'].